# Propositional Proofs

Tags: logic

I’m reading Introduction to Logic by Harry J. Gensler. I reached to Part Two, Chapter 7, Propositional Proofs (Easier proofs, s- and l-rules, RAA, how to derive, refutation…etc.)

What is the difference between what I did and what the author did?

here is the question:
[image]

and here is the writer's answer:
[image]

and here is my answer:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your step 7 is wrong.

See [Contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition): **(∼W ⊃ ∼G)** is equivalent to **(G ⊃ W)**.

From **(∼W ⊃ ∼G)** and **G** we cannot validly infer **∼W**. Consider the case when **G** and **W** are both TRUE: in this case the premises **(∼W ⊃ ∼G)** and **G** are TRUE but the conclusion **∼W** is FALSE.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
It seems that the book did not refer to this point that you mentioned, and that is why I made a mistake in my answer.
I think I misunderstood the words of the writer (page 148): here

https://image.ibb.co/jgYEfw/Capture.png

Comment: @MohammadAltamimi - exactly: see bottom left: from **(∼A ⊃ ∼B)** and **B**, derive **A**.